# Making EditText and Button same height in Android

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, android-layout

I have an `EditText` and a `Button` in my `LinearLayout` and I want to align them closely together so they see seem to belong together (edittext + micButton for speech input).

Now they don't have the same height and they aren't really aligned well (`Button` seems to be a little lower than the `EditText`). I know I can apply a negative margin like `-5dp` to make them come closer together, but is there perhaps a better way to do this?

Set them in a specific container/layout so that they will automatically have the same height and no margin between them?

Answer (score 1):

Using relative layout you can stretch a view depending upon another views size without knowing the exact size of the other view. 
Here is the code :

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
<Button 
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:text="button"
    android:id="@+id/but"/>
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/but"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/but"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/but"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Check this link for reducing space between views :
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/RNfAxbqbTIk

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, don't know why people bother so much with tables.  Since the both Views are within a LinearLayout (presumable orientation=Horizontal), this command should center both within the layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

**Note**: Since EditTexts and Buttons may orient their text slightly differently, you may have to do some tweaking (by changing margins or padding) to get the text to align properly.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this solution might help for your scenario...Here is the code..

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="3dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etId"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:background="#c8c8c8"
        android:hint="Edittext"
        android:paddingLeft="20dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlLayoutid"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etId" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/calender" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

@ Daniel Here You can use layout weight and weight sum

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weight_sum=2    
        >
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=1
        android:text="button"
        android:id="@+id/but"/>
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=1       
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Android tries to automatically level everything off of the text and not the buttons themselves.

Took me forever to finally figure it out.  Its really simple. Should fix it.

```
myButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```

or if they are in a row.. attach the buttons to a table row, then.

```
myTableRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```